# Trouble in displaying an input element after the click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have a function that is supposed to add an input element to an existing div. I have tried using appendChild and have tried concatenating the object to the innerHTML but none of these have worked. Is there something here that my newbie's brain is forgetting?

```
function addSong() {
  const additionDiv = document.getElementById('track-controls');
  const trackFileInput = document.createElement('input');
  additionDiv.innerHTML += trackFileInput;
  const trackFile = trackFileInput.value;
  console.log('file saved'+trackFile);
}
```

Kindly assume that the outer variables and IDs are all present in other parts of the code. This function is referenced in the onclick property of a button.
I have thoroughly checked for typos.

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed two competing methods for editing the DOM.  `innerHTML` wants a string, but you're feeding it a DOM node instead (and then trying to concatenate that node with the existing html string).  For a DOM node, you want to append the element (or use other [DOM manipulation methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/How_to_create_a_DOM_tree)):

```js
function addSong() {
  const additionDiv = document.getElementById('track-controls');

  const trackFileInput = document.createElement('input');
  additionDiv.appendChild(trackFileInput)
  
  const trackFile = trackFileInput.value; // note this will always be an empty string
  console.log('file saved' + trackFile);
}

addSong()
```

```html
<div id="track-controls"></div>
```